# Installing font-awesome with Laravel 9 (Vite)

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, font-awesome, vite

i'm using Laravel 9 which doesn't use mix anymore, but vite, to bundle resources, i'm also not using any preprocessors like sass or less and don't really know anything about them.

Every text about adding font awesome on the internet is for Laravel 8 and bellow which didn't use vite. Also they all require me to put the font awesome packs in app.sass file which i don't have and am not sure how exactly to install and use.

I'm a student and am developing the application for an offline presentation, so no CDN's allowed.

Could somebody explain the process of installing font awesome without sass and with vite, or if sass is a must, explain to me in short, what it is, how do i install it, and use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

add fontawesome library

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

in the file /resources/css/app.css:

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

then run

```
npm run build or npm run dev
```

Comment: When running sail use: ```sail npm run dev```

Answer (score 5):

So i figured it out. Turns out it's as simple as running

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and then adding

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

to your app.css file.
You can then proceed to use

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
```

and similar in your code.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I'm using FA in Laravel 9 with Vite. In addition to the NPM install, I have the following code in `vite.config.cs` and `resources/sass/app.scss`. Works as expected.

**vite.config.cs**

```
export default defineConfig({
    //... 
          plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~fa': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss'),
        }
    },
});
```

**resources/sass/app.scss**

```
$fa-font-path:"~fa/../webfonts";
@import "~fa/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~fa/solid.scss";
@import "~fa/regular.scss";
@import "~fa/brands.scss";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finally find the trick !** Import it to your app.js as the js file of the package has everything !

1 Install the package

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

2 Import it in resources/**js/app.js** It is better to import only what you need, to minimize the size.

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid';
```

3 Enjoy

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-sort"></i>
```

You also need to have sass installed. Nothing to change in vite conf.